# sqlalchemy with db2 and kerberos

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, db2, kerberos

How can I connect to my db2 database with sqlalchemy when the authentication is using kerberos?

When using pyodbc the connection string contains AuthenticationMethod=4, which lets kerberos handle the authentication and I don't need to provide username and password.

Is there a way to either pass a pyodbc.connect object directly into sqlalchemy or can I alternatively tell sqlalchemy to use kerberos?

My odbc connection string looks like this:

```
connstr = 'ApplicationUsingThreads=0;' \
  ...:               'FloatingPointParameters=0;' \
  ...:               'DoubleToStringPrecision=16;DB=NYRMPDI1;' \
  ...:               'AuthenticationMethod=4;' \
  ...:               f'IpAddress={ip_address};' \
  ...:               f'TcpPort={port};' \
  ...:               f'DRIVER={driver_location}'
```

I can't find any way to pass this into sqlalchemy create_engine.

Comment: Would this help? https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/connections.html#how-do-i-pass-custom-connect-arguments-to-my-database-api

Comment: it still needs a url. I need a version where I can only give it a connection string, same way as odbc

Comment: If all else fails, you can pass a custom function as the `creator` of connections, allowing just about any customization: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#custom-dbapi-connect-arguments

Comment: Ok, ignore the previous, it sounds like you want this: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#pass-through-exact-pyodbc-string

Comment: Actually it doesn't work. Getting this error: `sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('6000', '[6000] [DataDirect][ODBC 20101 driver]2755 (2755) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/dbapi)` when I try `engine.connect()`

Answer (score 1):

`ibm_db_sa` with an IBM Db2 driver supports kerberos connections with pyodbc, both DSN-LESS and DSN connection-strings, and it works with all three types of IBM Db2-driver (fat client, run-time-client, and ODBC and CLI driver). Different configurations are necessary for the fat-client+runtime-client, versus the ODBC and CLI client.

By default, unless you tell it otherwise, the installation of `ibm_db_sa` or `ibm_db` modules will install the IBM 'ODBC and CLI client'.

Your `odbcinst.ini` needs to define a driver-name (in my example I call it DB2CLI but you give it any name you prefer), and specify the library to load (example libdb2.so) from the correct path.

Here is an example of a DSN-LESS connection string, which you must urlencode before passing to `create_engine()`:

```
CONNECTION_STRING=("DRIVER={DB2CLI};HOSTNAME=192.168.1.178;PORT=60000;KRBPLUGIN=IBMkrb5;AUTHENTICATION=KERBEROS;DATABASE=SAMPLE;")

quoted_connection_string=urllib.parse.quote_plus(CONNECTION_STRING)

engine = create_engine('ibm_db_sa+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted_connection_string))
```

If you prefer a DSN connection, you must define all the details in  the `db2dsdriver.cfg` and have a stanza for the dsn in the active `odbc.ini` that references the driver you configured in your `odbcinst.ini`, and you must specify **only** the DSN in the connection-string like this:

```
CONNECTION_STRING=("DSN=SAMPLE;")

engine = create_engine('ibm_db_sa+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(CONNECTION_STRING))
```

For DSN connections, it helps if you first get the kerberos connection working with `isql` defore you get it working with sqlalchemy because the troubleshooting seems easier.

I tested with these component versions:

- ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64
- python 3.6.8 in a virtualenv
- ibm_db 3.0.1
- ibm_db_sa 0.3.5
- unixODBC 2.3.4
- pyodbc 4.0.30
- IBM Db2 data server driver 11.1.4.4a (**optional**)
- IBM Db2 ODBC and CLI driver (**default**)
- local and remote Db2-LUW servers whose Db2-instances are kerberized already.

Steps to try:

- For DSN connections, configure your active `db2dsdriver.cfg` with dsn and database with parameter Authentication, parameter value Kerberos.
- For the fat-client and runtime-client, configure your IBM Data Server Client `CLNT_KRB_PLUGIN` parameter to **IBMkrb5** via `db2 update dbm cfg using CLNT_KRB_PLUGIN IBMkrb5`. (You don't need this step when using the ODBC and CLI driver).
- Configure your active `odbcinst.ini` for Db2 to use the correct `libdb2.so` library as supplied by your Db2 client, and reference this driver-name either in your DSN-LESS python code, or in your `odbc.ini` for DSN-connections.
- For DSN connections only, configure your active `odbc.ini` to use the Db2 driver specified in `odbcinst.ini` and mention `Authentication = kerberos` in your DSN stanza in `odbc.ini`.
- For DSN connections, Omit any userid/password from the active `odbc.ini` file. For DSN-LESS connectiond you don't need any reference to the database in the `odbc.ini` or `db2dsdriver.cfg`.
- For DSN connections only, Verify `db2cli validate -dsn $YOURDSN -connect` for a remote database completes successfully without a userid or password. This proves that the CLI layer is using kerberos.
- (Optional) For Db2 fat client, or runtime client, verify you can connect to a catalogued remote database at the shell command line `db2 connect to $YOUR_REMOTE_DATABASE` (without needing to enter a userid/password). This proves that regular shell scripts can connect to the database with kerberos authentication.
- If you are using either the Db2 fat client, or the Db2 runtime client then you need to dot in / source the correct db2profile before running either `isql` or your python script.